# Integrals involving functions with big O notation

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics

Let,
$$f(x)=g(x)+\mathcal{O}(h(x))$$
As $x\to\infty$.
And suppose $F$ is integrable in some interval $[a,b]$.

Then is,
$$\int_{a}^{b}F(x)df(x)=\int_{a}^{b}F(x)dg(x)+\mathcal{O}\left(\int_{a}^{b}F(x)dh(x)\right)$$
True??
If yes then what's the intuition behind?

So basically my problem is this,
Poisson showed that,
$$\pi(x)=\operatorname{li}(x)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{x}{e^{a\sqrt{x}}}\right)$$
As $x\to\infty$

I was thinking about,
$$\theta(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}\ln p$$
and show that $\theta(x)$ is asymptotic to $x$.

I did it like this but just wondering if it's true.
$$\theta(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}\ln p =\sum_{k=2}^{x}\ln k\left(\pi(k)-\pi(k-1)\right)$$
So I doubt the next step and request an explanation,
$$\theta(x)=\int_{2}^{x}\ln k d\pi(k)$$
So from the PNT,
$$\int_{2}^{x}dk+\int_{2}^{x}\ln k dR(k)$$
Where $R(x)=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{x}{e^{a\sqrt{x}}}\right)$
Using by parts it's easier to show that the second integral is $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Which completes the proof.
I was just wondering if I am right??

Comment: Big O as ...? Usually you define specify some limit

Comment: The question does not make sense. In the hypothesis you should say $as x \to ?$ Otheriwse $O(x)$ has no meaning.

Comment: @dmh,@geetha290krm I missed that. My bad.

Comment: I fixed it now. Any help??

Comment: You also need to assume that f(x), g(x), h(x) are differentiable in [a,b]. I think your equality is not generally true, unless you let a, b approaching infinity. It is weird, though.

Comment: What does $O$ mean in the conclusion part? Big $O$ as what? What is your variable there?

Comment: It was shown by de La Vallée *Poussin* and not Poisson.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b$ are bounded then I don't see why this claim would be true. We don't know how $f$ behaves on the interval of interest.

Also, we need a limit for the last big O notation you use as well.